# PHP file downloads on direct visit

Tags: php, .htaccess, download

I am very much aware that PHP is a server side language and therefore should not allow the php file to be downloaded. However, on direct visit in Chrome to the PHP file, it downloads an obfuscated version of the file, something I'd like to prevent. Is there a way to stop the file  from being served up?

**The code is below.** 
The system works to perfection inside WordPress, but if I open up Chrome (and I presume others) and visit the update.php file directly, it downloads.

Notably, I tried to echo an HTML page but it messes up the way the system works. I'm hoping there's some sort of .htaccess trick for this.

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
  switch ($_POST['action']) {
    case 'version':
      echo '1.1';
      break;
    case 'info':
      $obj = new stdClass();
      $obj->slug = 'plugin.php';
      $obj->plugin_name = 'plugin.php';
      $obj->new_version = '1.1';
      $obj->requires = '3.0';
      $obj->tested = '3.3.1';
      $obj->downloaded = 12540;
      $obj->last_updated = '2012-01-12';
      $obj->sections = array(
        'description' => 'The new version of the Auto-Update plugin',
        'another_section' => 'This is another section',
        'changelog' => 'Some new features'
      );
      $obj->download_link = 'http://localhost/update.php';
      echo serialize($obj);
    case 'license':
      echo 'false';
      break;
  }
} else {
    header('Cache-Control: public');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    readfile('update.zip');
}
```

Comment: We prefer the code be posted here to following a link.  Reasonable amounts of relevant code aren't considered clutter.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure as to how much code would be considered acceptable. Duly noted.

Comment: @Michael any idea as to why it's downloading? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The file is downloading because of the header content type you set, which in most browsers prompts download.

Comment: @chriscct7 See my answer below...

Comment: also see my additional comment in your switch/case you are missing the break at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, if it does not receive `$_POST['action']`, then sends `update.zip` to the browser in the `else` case.

What you are seeing when visit the file not via a POST is not obfuscated PHP.  Rather, it is sending the contents of the file `update.zip` to the browser for download.  But since the code doesn't supply a filename hint in the headers, it doesn't come as `update.zip` and instead probably looks like a .php file with the same name as your script.

If you want `update.zip` to look like a zip file, add a `filename` into the `Content-Disposition` output header:

```
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');

// Change to attachment disposition, with filename
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=update.zip');
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
readfile('update.zip');
```

Now, if you *don't* want it sending `update.zip` at all, remove the entire `else {}` block from the bottom, and replace it with something like

```
else {
  echo "You must supply an action...";
}
```

#### Update: To restrict access only to referrals by `wp_autoupdate.php`

Consult `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']`, but know that the value of this can be spoofed. This cannot be used with 100% reliability.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'wp_autoupdate.php') !== FALSE) {
  // Include all your exsiting code
}
else {
  // Don't do anything, or redirect somewhere else
  header("Location: /");
  exit();
}
```

To achieve 100% reliability, you would probably need to modify `wp_autoupdate.php` to set a session variable which is then checked by `update.php`, ensuring the request came from the right place.

Comment: While that did stop the issue, its created another one. The code is being used to update a premium plugin, and thus with the addition of your code, it now downloads a copy of the plugin (something I want to avoid). Is there a way to throw an (pardon the pseudocode)  
If (wordpress){  
use the headers I already have  
}  
Else  
serve a blank page or something  
  
?

Comment: @chriscct7 that's what I just added above, replacing the `else {}` case.

Comment: But I need those headers, otherwise WordPress will not do the update.

Comment: What is the name of the script which posts to update.php? You could check the referrer and abort if it isn't correct.

Comment: How do I check the referring script?

Comment: @chriscct7 see additions above.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking one more question, can I edit     `readfile('update.zip');` to make it like   `readfile('3fdg34v344t\update.zip');` where that blob is a directory? If so, is it `readfile('\3fdg34v344t\update.zip');` or `readfile('3fdg34v344t\update.zip');` ?

Comment: @chriscct7 Sure, of course.  But if it is windows, use \\ (double-backslash) and if it is a Unix server, use `/` (forward slash).

Comment: What if it's a Linux server. Still forward slash?

Comment: @chriscct7 Unix =~ Linux, MacOS, Solaris, etc.  So yes, forward slash

Answer (score 0):

You set the content type to application/zip which in most browsers prompts a download.  Is there a chance that you're not passing an "action" via POST and that is why it's hitting that else section?

One more thing I see is you have no

```
break;
```

In your second switch/case.

```
      $obj->download_link = 'http://localhost/update.php';
      echo serialize($obj);
      break;  // <------ this is missing!
    case 'license':
      echo 'false';
      break;
```

---

Have you checked out this article: http://konstruktors.com/blog/wordpress/2538-automatic-updates-for-plugins-and-themes-hosted-outside-wordpress-extend/

---

Regarding restricting access to the file to everyone except WordPress, it's unknown if you host your WordPress site or not.  If you do, you could restrict access to localhost or 127.0.0.1 in your .htaccess file.  If it's hosted on WordPress.com you find their IP or hostname and change it.

```
<Files update.php>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

Comment: This along with the headers makes my problem more interesting. The headers right now are needed so WordPress downloads the update, but on the other hand, those same headers are also allowing normal people to download the zip file. How can I avoid this?

Comment: How would anyone know about that path update.php or are you concerned someone might guess it?

Comment: I added a suggested .htaccess config.  Given someone visiting is not POSTing the data to the site, they will always hit your else condition that delivers the header and prompts the download.  You can restrict access like I showed, or you can change your logic and not include the header in the else condition, but that might be required by WordPress.

Comment: This is for a WordPress plugin. Therefore, I do not know the ip addresses of every user. As for the link, it shows up during hte update process when you upgrade a plugin in WP.

Comment: So you are hosting the plugin for others' sites.  I see.  Does the file have to be called update.php or can you obfuscate it?  If it has to be that file, someone could "guess" the path/name.  Perhaps you're over-thinking it and if you allow people to download this update.zip then if they guess it, just let it download.  If that's the case, simply fix your header so it saves the file name correctly and don't worry about it.

Comment: You know what Mike, I just realized something. In order to see this URL during the update process, you have to already have this plugin. So all I really need to do is obfuscate the upgrade.php name and then stop worrying. I feel like a moron now :( ThX for your help.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking one more question, can I edit     `readfile('update.zip');` to make it like   `readfile('3fdg34v344t\update.zip');` where that blob is a directory? If so, is it `readfile('\3fdg34v344t\update.zip');` or `readfile('3fdg34v344t\update.zip');` ?

Comment: yes, you can.  that's what I meant about obfuscating the file or directory but note if someone visits your page it will download because they are not POSTing anything.  so if the zip file is hosted in a hidden directory, it really solves nothing, and it's the path to the update.php file you should concern.  If you're allowing anyone to download this via plugin, I'd not worry because anyone could get it anyway.

Comment: Right I am also planning now on obfuscating both the directories and name of the upgrade file. Thanks for the tips :)

Comment: I wish I could. It won't let me up yours because of my reputation :(

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. Great idea on building your own plugin (huge audience)